# Is it okay to get a reference to an object that is retrieved from dereferencing an iterator returned by std::find_if? &*x

Tags: c++

Consider the following case where I have a struct and a vector of that struct.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    uint32_t id;
    std::string name;
    float length;
}


std::vector<MyStruct> myStuff;
```

Now I want to search for a specific object inside of this and edit its values, which I am performing as:

```
void EditSomeThing(uint32_t id, const std::string& newName)
{
    if(auto item = &*std::find_if(mystuff.begin(), mystuff.end(), [&id](const MyStruct& ms) { return ms.id == id; } ))
    {
        item->name = newName;
    }
}
```

I want to know if this is fine. I am new to C++ and I am not sure if I should be using that scary combination of ampersand and asterisk.

Even if it is fine I am open to knowing if there is any better way to approach this.

Comment: Also since you're new to C++, what are you using to learn C++ from? (There are a lot of low quality or obsolete sources out there). Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Oh yes I did use a `const std::string&` but forgot to put it in this example since I didn't copy paste the code and yeah pretty sure it should be `item->name = newName` because I am assigning and not comparing. Also, I am a previous C# programmer trying to learn C++. Till now I have been using random sources around the internet but I do use cppreference when I don't understand something. I was thinking of getting the C++ Programming language book (I hope it is a good source, lmk if it isn't). I will definitely check out learncpp and the core guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Well the thing with books is, they're usually outdated a bit. And a lot of books start over with the basics (and use a lot of raw pointers still, where they should teach the use of C++ classes like std::string_view, std::span, std::array and std::vector) and to (almost) never use `new/delete` again use std::make_unique (or if you are really sure you needed it std::shared_ptr). But yes you could use a book but also be sure to cross reference it with the core guidelines (limit the use of raw pointers/new/delete is a good start).

Comment: As for C# programmer pitfalls, make sure you really understand how C++ manages objects differently than C#. So read up on [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and the (strangely named) concept of [RAII (Resource acquisition is initialization)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). RAII is a very very useful tool when combined with scopes (and error handling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not ok, since if `find_if` returns `mystuff.end()` it will dereference the `end()` iterator, which has undefined behavior. Your lambda function should also `return` the result of the comparison, but it currently does not.

You'd better split it up:

```cpp
auto item = std::find_if(mystuff.begin(), mystuff.end(),
                         [&id](const MyStruct& ms) { return ms.id == id; });

if (item != mystuff.end()) {
    item->name = newName;
}
```

Since C++17 you may also use an [`if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#If_statements_with_initializer) with an *init-statement* to limit the scope of `item`:

```cpp
if (auto item = std::find_if(mystuff.begin(), mystuff.end(),
                             [&id](const MyStruct& ms) { return ms.id == id; });
    item != mystuff.end())
{
    item->name = newName;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I did not copy paste the entire code but made a quick example so I missed the return, my bad. And thanks for the insight. I did not know dereferencing end() was undefined behavior, I assumed it would just return a nullptr. The C++17 idea seems really nice. Thanks!

Comment: @PotatoMan Glad it helped! Mind though that dereferencing `nullptr` also has undefined behavior.